# CSS float proprerty issue ( + guidance )

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need some help figuring out why my layout is messy. Here is what I was working on :[The Site](http://eclesia.org/petros/dev/test/). The green box should be inside the purple box. I think there is a floating issue. Since I don't fully understand the `float` rules can someone help me identify the problem and suggest some good "old" documentation reading?

Thank you!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best for useful background reading and answers to your problem

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on #content

Comment: My recommended solution is to use `display:inline-block` elements and avoid floating elements altogether

Comment: @Adam this is working but can you tell me some consequences by using this? Or there aren't any, because if i have  `height:auto` the content will never be overflowing.

Comment: I've used that method for as long as I can remember and from my experience it's consistent in most browsers. I can't remember what it's like in <=IE7 but IE8+ it's good. The only issues I can think of are if you need the wrapper to be a fixed height. It will obviously cut off any overflowing content (Note, you can also use `overflow: scroll` I believe). Also in some instances you may have a fixed container at `200px` tall with two `div`'s floated left and right inside it. If you had an item inside one of the children that expanded on click (e.g. facebook `Like` button) it will also get cut off

Comment: And some light reading on the topic [Float containment](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/), and [The magic of “overflow: hidden”](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an *overflow: hidden;* to the div with id: content-n

```
#content-n {
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why is this happening? Some consequences maybe? It works but... why?

Comment: The #content div contains the #content-n div which has no height property given. If you add the overflow:hidden; property to it, than it will have the height of the element in it, so the height of the #nav_cat element. So when #content-n has a height, too, the #content div will strech to "contain" that element.

Comment: Yep!  I just figured it out by myself. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Cool. If this was the answer what you were looking for, then you can accept it, too :)

Comment: @Seer please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: Thank you @andyb for the usefull information.

Answer (score 0):

Float removes the item from the document flow.

Add an empty `<div>` or `<span>` and give it the CSS `clear: both;`.
This will make the div clear the floated element and it's parent will then expand to the full height.

Read up on [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) and [floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) - particularly the section titles "Techniques for Clearing Floats".

**Source(s)**

[CSS Clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)
[All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: so this explains why if i remove the `float` property everything enters (visualy) back in the box.

Answer (score 0):

The items inside your `#container` are all floating left.

This means that they'll all stack up to the left until they reach the width of the containing element, at which time they'll start to wrap (as has happened in your case).

The containing element that holds the floating items will not expand to contain floating elements. One way you can force this is to do something like:

```
#container:after{
 content: ".";
 clear: left;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

This basically adds a full stop at the end of the div, sets it to clear left (so it clears all the floating items), and is then set to be invisible, forcing the container to extend past its content.

Comment: what `content:"."` does?

Comment: It adds a dot (full stop) to the bottom of the containing div. See the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Here is what I would like to recommend you to read on Float

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Apart from that, if you edit #content positioning from relative to absolute. That will wrap green box inside purple since it will take position related to parent (#content that is)..

```
#content {
   position: absolute;
   ..
   ..
   ..
}
```

Floating is very good feature when used with care.